# I don't understand this proof: Trichotomy for ordinals (by double transfinite induction)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

[image]

Hello everyone!

The proof is from this book: https://st.openlogicproject.org/

I think I understand the black bracket (checked). What worries me is the blue bracket (question mark).

As far as I understand, generally speaking, a 'double induction' would "nest" two inductions "into one another", so to speak: Like there is the 'big' surrounding/outer induction on the one side, and one or maybe more 'small' inner inductions happening (as it were) in the middle of it all, on the other side. Right?

Wouldn't we want, then, to show that the if-clause is fulfilled for the outer induction (and maybe, to this end, there will already be neccessary a little induction inside)? For then, we could use the induction (which is a theorem in this case) to show what we want to show?

Instead, we suppose something to do with $\alpha$ and any ordinal, and then, we suppose something 'for further induction'...I really don't know what is going on in this whole paragraph, which appearently explains a plan for how the proof is supposed to work out.

Thanks for reading. :)

Any hints, remarks and suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: Please try to avoid relying on information that appears on images and is not otherwise available in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this causes accessibility problems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is general structure of the proof:

We want to prove that for every ordinal $\alpha$, for every ordinal $\beta$, $\alpha$ is comparable to $\beta$.

Proceeding by induction on $\alpha$, we assume that every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal, and want to prove that $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal.

So we assume every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal. Now we want to prove that for every ordinal $\beta$, $\alpha$ is comparable to $\beta$.

But this is something we want to establish "for every ordinal", and as such we can use induction on ordinals to establish it (induction on $\beta$). So we assume that $\alpha$ is comparable to every element of $\beta$, and want to prove that $\alpha$ is comparable to $\beta$.

So we have two "inductive hypotheses":

1. For the induction on $\alpha$, we are assuming that every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal. We want to prove that
   $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal $\beta$.
2. For the subsequent induction on $\beta$, we are assuming that $\alpha$ is comparable to every element of $\beta$. We want to prove that

> > $\alpha$ is then comparable to $\beta$.

If we prove $\alpha$ is comparable to $\beta$ from these assumptions, we will prove that:

> If every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal, then $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal.

And that will prove, by induction, that

> Every ordinal $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal.

which is what we want to prove.

Since proving

> > $\alpha$ is comparable to $\beta$

means proving that either $\alpha\in\beta$ or $\beta\in\alpha$ or $\alpha=\beta$, we can assume $\alpha\notin \beta$, and $\beta\notin\alpha$, and try to prove $\alpha=\beta$.

So our "outside induction hypothesis" is that every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal. *And* our "inner induction hypothesis" is that $\alpha$ is comparable to every element of $\beta$. So to list our assumptions:

1. Every element of $\alpha$ is comparable to every ordinal ("outer" induction hypothesis).
2. $\alpha$ is comparable to every element of $\beta$ ("inner" induction hypothesis).
3. $\alpha\notin \beta$;
4. $\beta\notin\alpha$.

We want to prove that $\alpha=\beta$.

You use 1, 3, and 4 to prove that $\alpha\subseteq\beta$. Then you use 2, 3, and 4 to prove that $\beta\subseteq\alpha$. That proves $\alpha=\beta$, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and rigorous answer!...I did not have the time yet to read carefully through. I will get back soon if there are any further questions..GREAT :)

Comment: I am sorry but I have do admit that I still can't see how exactly I am supposed to apply the induction theorem. This theorem (or, equivalently, its reformulation in contraposition), are if-then-propositions. So, if I want to apply it, I need to fulfill the if-clause. I somebody has the time, I am still curious what exact formulae I would have to 'plug-in' for $\varphi$. Have I maybe not even understood how induction generally works (here)? I have the feel that I almost got it, I tried two times with some effort to make the proof work..

Comment: @Ettore The proposition is "x is comparable to y". The "outer" induction is on x, the "inner" one on y.

Comment: @Ettore The way ordinal induction works is that you show that if the proposition holds for all elements of $\beta$, then it holds for $\beta$. This is the analogue in "usual" induction (2nd principle) of showing that if the proposition holds for all $k\lt n$, then it holds for $n$.

Comment: I finally got it now!! :) Thank you very much for your patience...in the first/outer application of the induction-theorem I can use $\varphi(A) = \forall B: A$ is comp. to $B$. And in the second/inner application I can use $\varphi(B) = A$ is comp. to $B$, where $A$ is fixed by its context.